# How to use only half of my android screen by default

Tags: keyboard, phone-app, digital-wellbeing

Context: I wanted to reduce my screen time.  I have been using my phone in grayscale and it helps. The other thing I used to do was put my samsung phone in ultra power saving mode which would only let me use only 8 apps but this features was removed in the latest update.

So I was looking at dumb phones or features phones but I don't want to  miss out on the core apps like maps, Spotify, whatsapp, and a good camera.

I came across xiaomi's duoqin f22 which is an android phone with t9 physical keyboard and it was perfect for what I was looking for.  Not letting go android but very small screen size and physical keyboard.

But before making that purchase I wanted to see if there is a way to make my existing android phone Samsung A52 to use only top half the screen by default for all my apps. The bottom half can be a keyboard that is open all the time maybe.

I would like to know if this is achievable without root or crazy mods. Thank you :)